# RichTextBox in DataTemplate not filling

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, datatemplate

I have a `RichTextBox` in a `DataTemplate` and it is not filling the space while other controls are.  It is as if the `RichTextBox` is set to a Width="1"   Here is my `DataTemplate`;

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate" >
   <StackPanel>
       <RichTextBox />
       <TextBox />
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate >
```

This is what it looks like if I type "12345" with no spaces or returns;
[image]

Also here is how I use the `DataTemplate` ;

```
<ListBox  Margin="2" SelectionMode="Single" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}"/>
```

Note:  If I sent the `RichTextBox`  `MinWidth` to something it does make it better (for example "12345" would appear correctly), but still does not fill the space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate" >
        <StackPanel x:Name="Panel">
            <RichTextBox Width="{Binding ElementName=Panel, Path=ActualWidth}" />
            <TextBox />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate >
```

And your list:

> ```
> <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}"
>          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
>          ItemsSource="{Binding }"/>
> ```